# Read from a BufferedReader more than once in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, urlconnection

**I have the following piece of code in Java:**

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
con.connect();
InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
```

**At this point, I read the file from start to end while searching for something:**

```
while (true)
{
    String line = file.readLine();
    if (line == null)
        break;
    // Search for something...
}
```

Now I want to search for something else within the file, **without opening another URL connection**.

For reasons unrelated to this question, I wish to avoid searching for both things "in a single file-sweep".

#### Questions:

1. Can I rewind the file with `reset`?
2. If yes, should I apply it on the `InputStream` object, on the `BufferedReader` object or on both?
3. If no, then should I simply close the file and reopen it?
4. If yes, should I apply it on the `InputStream` object, on the `BufferedReader` object or on both?
5. If no, how else can I sweep the file again, without reading through the URL connection again?

Comment: Read the `InputStream` into a `ByteArrayInputStream` and re-read from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewind the file with `reset()`, provided that you have `mark()`'ed the position you want to rewind to. These methods should be invoked on the decorator, i.e. `BufferedReader`.

However, you may probably want to reconsider your design as you can easily read the whole file into some data structure (even a list of strings, or some stream backed by a string) and use the data multiple times.

Comment: So all I need to do is `file.mark(some large value)` before the first sweep, and `file.reset()` before the second sweep?

Comment: Exactly. But I still encourage you to rethink your design.

Comment: OK, sorry. We wrote our two comments at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following methods:

- `mark`
- `skip`
- `reset`

You can do it only if `markSupported()` returns `true`. Please note that actually reader typically does not add this functionality but delegates it to wrapped intput stream, so always call `markSupported()` and keep in mind that it can return `false` for streams that do not support this feature.

For example it really can happen for URL based streams: think, how can you reset stream that is originated from remote server. This may require client side to cache all content that you have already downloaded.

Comment: As per the docs, BufferedReader has its own buffer and always supports mark().

Comment: You are right. But as far as I remember it is limited by kind of 64K or probably more, but anyway it is not unlimited. I met this problem when reading from output stream of external process.

Comment: I see. The javadoc however just says: `A limit value larger than the size of the input buffer will cause a new buffer to be allocated whose size is no smaller than limit. Therefore large values should be used with care.` There is no "limit to `limit`" advertised, however I consider this an ill-designed process and I advised the OP to rethink his/her design.

Answer (score 0):

I usually end up using something like [InputStreamSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamSource.html) to make re-reading convenient. When I'm dealing with connections, I find it useful to use an in-memory or on-disk spooling strategy for re-reading. Use a threshold for choosing storage location, "tee" into the spool on first read, and re-read from the spool on subsequent reads.

Edit: Also found guavas [ByteSource](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteSource.html) and CharSource which have the same purpose.